# Getting the value of textbox and pass it to php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm building a system with a auto computation**

I need a suggestion or answer how to get the value of the text box (totalmiscexpense,,totalexpenses,totalinc) and pass to it to PHP so that I can initiate the UPDATE query onto my database

I have tried the code below but sometimes the value of textbox became "undefine" and I can't get the output that i want Please help!

Below is the code of my form named *edit_record.php*

```html
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#update").click(function() {

     var totalmiscexpenses = $('#totalmiscexpense').val();
     var totalexpenses = $('#totalexpenses').val();
     var totalinc = $('#totalinc').val();
     var recdate = $('#recdate').val();
     var bill = $('#bill').val();
     var disp = $('#disp').val();
     var broker = $('#broker').val();
     var headown = $('#headown').val();
     var plateno = $('#plateno').val();
     var consize = $('#consize').val();
     var conweight = $('#conweight').val();
     var desonefrom = $('#desonefrom').val();
     var desoneto = $('#desoneto').val();
     var destwofrom = $('#destwofrom').val();
     var destwoto = $('#destwoto').val();
     var gpreone = $('#gpreone').val();
     var gpretwo = $('#gpretwo').val();
     var dieselone = $('#dieselone').val();
     var disoneam = $('#disoneam').val();
     var dieseltwo = $('#dieseltwo').val();
     var distwoam = $('#distwoam').val();
     var togateone = $('#togateone').val();
     var togateam = $('#togateam').val();
     var togatewo = $('#togatewo').val();
     var togatwoam = $('#togatwoam').val();
     var expones = $('#expones').val();
     var exponeam = $('#exponeam').val()
     var exptwos = $('#exptwos').val();
     var exptwoam = $('#exptwoam').val();
     var exptree = $('#exptree').val();
     var exptream = $('#exptream').val();
     var expfors = $('#expfors').val();
     var expforam = $('#expforam').val();
     var expfives = $('#expfives').val();
     var expfiveam = $('#expfiveam').val();
     var expsixs = $('#expsixs').val();
     var expsixam = $('#expsixam').val();
     var expsevs = $('#expsevs').val();
     var expsevam = $('#expsevam').val();
     var expeyts = $('#expeyts').val();
     var expeytam = $('#expeytam').val();
     var expnines = $('#expnines').val();
     var expnineam = $('#expnineam').val();
     var exptens = $('#exptens').val();
     var exptenam = $('#exptenam').val();
     var expelevs = $('#expelevs').val();
     var expelevam = $('#expelevam').val();
     var drivername = $('#drivername').val();
     var driversal = $('#driversal').val();
     var helpname = $('#helpname').val();
     var helpsal = $('#helpsal').val();
     var income = $('#income').val();

     var datas = 'totalmiscexpenses=' + totalmiscexpenses + '&totalexpenses=' + totalexpenses + '&totalinc=' + totalinc + '&recdate=' + recdate + '&bill=' + bill + '&disp=' + disp + '&broker=' + broker + '&headown=' + headown + '&plateno=' + plateno + '&consize=' + consize + '&conweight=' + conweight + '&desonefrom=' + desonefrom + '&desoneto=' + desoneto + '&destwofrom=' + destwofrom + '&destwoto=' + destwoto + '&gpreone=' + gpreone + '&gpretwo=' + gpretwo + '&dieselone=' + dieselone + '&disoneam=' + disoneam + '&dieseltwo=' + dieseltwo + '&distwoam=' + distwoam + '&togateone=' + togateone + '&togateam=' + togateam + '&togatewo=' + togatewo + '&togatwoam=' + togatwoam + '&expones=' + expones + '&exponeam=' + exponeam + '&exptwos=' + exptwos + '&exptwoam=' + exptwoam + '&exptree=' + exptree + '&exptream=' + exptream + '&expfors=' + expfors + '&expforam=' + expforam + '&expfives=' + expfives + '&expfiveam=' + expfiveam + '&expsixs=' + expsixs + '&expsixam=' + expsixam + '&expsevs=' + expsevs + '&expsevam=' + expsevam + '&expeyts=' + expeyts + '&expeytam=' + expeytam + '&expnines=' + expnines + '&expnineam=' + expnineam + '&exptens=' + exptens + '&exptenam=' + exptenam + '&expelevs=' + expelevs + '&expelevam=' + expelevam + '&drivername=' + drivername + '&driversal=' + driversal + '&helpname=' + helpname + '&helpsal=' + helpsal + '&income=' + income;
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "updaterecord.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data: datas,
       success: function() {

         window.location('record_list.php');

       }
     });

   });
 });
</script>
<?php
      $query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_records where id='$ID'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
      ?>                    
            <form method="post" id="entryVal" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="">

            <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Record ID </label>
      <input type="number" name="ID" value="<?php  echo $row['id']; ?>" class="form-control" 
       placeholder="test" disabled/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Date Encoded </label>
      <input type="text" name="recdate" value="<?php echo $row['recdate']; ?>" class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Date" disabled/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Date Recorded </label>
      <input type="date" name="recdate" value="<?php echo $row['date']; ?>" class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Date"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Way Bill No.</label>
      <input type="text" name="bill" value="<?php echo $row['billNum']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Bill number" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Dispatcher </label>
      <input type="text" name="disp" value="<?php echo $row['disPatcher']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Mr. / Mrs. " />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Broker </label>
      <input type="text" name="broker" value="<?php echo $row['broKer']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Mr. / Mrs." />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label > Tractor Head Owner </label>
      <input type="text" name="headown" value="<?php echo $row['hOwner']; ?>"class="form-control"  placeholder="test" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label> Plate Number </label>
      <input type="text" name="plateno" value="<?php echo $row['pNumb']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="test" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label> Container Size </label>
      <input type="text" name="consize" value="<?php echo $row['conSize']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="test" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Container Gross Weight </label>
      <input type="text" name="conweight" value="<?php echo $row['grossWeight']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="test" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Destination 1 </label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="desonefrom" value="<?php echo $row['desoneFrom']; ?>" class="form-control"placeholder="From" style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" name="desoneto" value="<?php echo $row['desoneTo']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="To" style="width:49%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Destination 2 </label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="destwofrom" value="<?php echo $row['destwoFrom']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="From" style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" name="destwoto" value="<?php echo $row['destwoTo']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="To" style="width:49%">
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label> Gross Preight 1 </label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['grossPreone']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="From" name="gpreone">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Gross Preight 2 </label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['grossPretwo']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="From" name="gpretwo">

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6">

  <div class="form-group">
  <h4> Less:
    <button id="showM"type="button" class="btn-sm btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> </span> Show more 
    </button> 

    <button id="showL"type="button" class="btn-sm btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"> </span> Show less 
    </button> 
  </h4> 


  </div>

  <div id="less">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Diesel 1 </label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="dieselone" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['dieselOne']; ?>" placeholder="What diesel" style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['dieseOnelAm']; ?>" id="diesel1" name="disoneam" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" style="width:49%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Diesel 2 </label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="dieseltwo" value="<?php echo $row['dieselTwo']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="What diesel" style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['dieselTwoAm']; ?>" id="diesel2" name="distwoam" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" style="width:49%">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Toll Gate 1 </label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="togateone" value="<?php echo $row['tolloneFrom']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Toll from" style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['tolloneAm']; ?>" id="tollone" name="togateam" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" style="width:49%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Toll Gate 2 </label>
          <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['tolltwoFrom']; ?>" name="togatetwo" class="form-control" placeholder="Toll from" style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="tolltwo" name="togatwoam" value="<?php echo $row['tolltwoAm']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" style="width:49%">
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="Form-inline">
      <label> Miscellanaous expenses: </label>

        <button id="miscShw"type="button" class="btn-sm btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> </span> Add 
        </button> 

        <button id="miscLss"type="button" class="btn-sm btn-danger" aria-label="Left Align">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"> </span> 
         Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['exOne']; ?>" name="expone" class="form-control" placeholder="Expenses" style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="expone" name="exponeam" value="<?php echo $row['exOneam']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text"name="exptwo" value="<?php echo $row['exTwo']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="exptwo" name="exptwoam" value="<?php echo $row['exTwoam']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['exThree']; ?>" name="exptre" class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="exptre" name="exptream" value="<?php echo $row['exThreeam']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="expfor" value="<?php echo $row['exFour']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="expfor" name="expforam"  value="<?php echo $row['exFouram']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="expfive" value="<?php echo $row['exFive']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['exFiveam']; ?>" id="expfive" name="expfiveam" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div id="6" class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="expsix" value="<?php echo $row['exSix']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="expsix" value="<?php echo $row['exSixam']; ?>"name="expsixam" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div id="7" class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="expsev" value="<?php echo $row['exSeven']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="expsev" value="<?php echo $row['exSevenam']; ?>"name="expsevam" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div id="8" class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="expeyt" value="<?php echo $row['exEight']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="expeyt" name="expeytam" value="<?php echo $row['exEightam']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div id="9" class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="expnine" value="<?php echo $row['exNine']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="expnine" name="expnineam" value="<?php echo $row['exNineam']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div id="10" class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="expten" value="<?php echo $row['exTen']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="expten"  name="exptenam" value="<?php echo $row['exTenam']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div id="11" class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="expelev" value="<?php echo $row['exElev']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="expenses"style="width:49%">
            <input type="text" id="expelev" name="expelevam" value="<?php echo $row['exElevam']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Price"style="width:49%">
          </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="red"> Total Misc. Expenses* </label>
            <input type="text" id="totalmiscexpense" name="totalmisc" value="<?php echo $row['totalMisc']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Driver </label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="drivername" value="<?php echo $row['driverName']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Name" style="width:49%;">
            <input type="text" name="drivsal" value="<?php echo $row['driverSal']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Salary" id="driversal" style="width:49%;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Helper </label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="helpname" value="<?php echo $row['helpName']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" style="width:49%;">
            <input type="text" name="helpsal" value="<?php echo $row['helpSal']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Salary" id="helpsal" style="width:49%;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="red"> Total Expenses* </label>
            <input type="text" id="totalexpenses" name="totalexpense" value="<?php echo $row['totalExpense']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Salary" disabled/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label> NET Income </label>
            <input type="text" id="income" name="netincome" value="<?php echo $row['income']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Amount">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="red"> Total Income* </label>
            <input type="text" id="totalinc" name="totalinc" value="<?php echo $row['totalincome']; ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" disabled/>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>     
  </div>
            <div class="form-group center">

                  <button type="submit" name="update" id="update" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Update</button>

             </div>

            </form>
```

BELOW is the code of updaterecord.php

```
<?php

include('include/database.php');
include('session.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$_POST = stripslashes_deep($_POST); 
    $recdate=$_POST['recdate'];
    $bill=$_POST['bill'];
    $disp=$_POST['disp'];
    $broker=$_POST['broker'];
    $headown=$_POST['headown'];
    $plateno=$_POST['plateno'];
    $consize=$_POST['consize'];
    $conweight=$_POST['conweight'];
    $desonefrom=$_POST['desonefrom'];
    $desoneto=$_POST['desoneto'];
    $destwofrom=$_POST['destwofrom'];
    $destwoto=$_POST['destwoto'];
    $gpreone=$_POST['gpreone'];
    $gpretwo=$_POST['gpretwo'];
    $dieselone=$_POST['dieselone'];
    $disoneam=$_POST['disoneam'];
    $dieseltwo=$_POST['dieseltwo'];
    $distwoam=$_POST['distwoam'];
    $togateone=$_POST['togateone'];
    $togateam=$_POST['togateam'];
    $togatewo=$_POST['togatewo'];
    $togatwoam=$_POST['togatwoam'];
    $expones=$_POST['expones'];
    $exponeam=$_POST['exponeam'];
    $exptwos=$_POST['exptwos'];
    $exptwoam=$_POST['exptwoam'];
    $exptree=$_POST['exptree'];
    $exptream=$_POST['exptream'];
    $expfors=$_POST['expfors'];
    $expforam=$_POST['expforam'];
    $expfives=$_POST['expfives'];
    $expfiveam=$_POST['expfiveam'];
    $expsixs=$_POST['expsixs'];
    $expsixam=$_POST['expsixam'];
    $expsevs=$_POST['expsevs'];
    $expsevam=$_POST['expsevam'];
    $expeyts=$_POST['expeyts'];
    $expeytam=$_POST['expeytam'];
    $expnines=$_POST['expnines'];
    $expnineam=$_POST['expnineam'];
    $exptens=$_POST['exptens'];
    $exptenam=$_POST['exptenam'];
    $expelevs=$_POST['expelevs'];
    $expelevam=$_POST['expelevam'];
    $income=$_POST['income'];
    $drivername=$_POST['drivername'];
    $driversal=$_POST['driversal'];
    $helpname=$_POST['helpname'];
    $helpsal=$_POST['helpsal'];


    $totalmiscexpenses = $_POST['totalmiscexpenses'];
    $totalexpenses = $_POST['totalexpenses'];
    $totalinc = $_POST['totalinc'];


    //audit trail
    $history_record=mysql_query("SELECT * from user where user_id=$id_session");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($history_record);
    $user=$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO history (date,action,data) VALUES (NOW(),'New Record','$user')")or die(mysql_error());

    //query for records

    $queryupdate= mysql_query ("UPDATE tbl_records SET billNum='$bill',disPatcher='$disp',broKer='$broker',hOwner='$headown',pNumb='$plateno',conSize='$consize',grossWeight='$conweight',desoneFrom='$desonefrom',desoneTo='$desoneto',destwoFrom='$destwofrom', destwoTo='$destwoto',grossPreone='$gpreone',grossPretwo='$gpretwo',dieselOne='$dieselone',dieseOnelAm='$disoneam',dieselTwo='$dieseltwo',dieselTwoAm='$distwoam',tolloneFrom='$togateone',tolloneAm='$togateam',tolltwoFrom='$togatewo',tolltwoAm='$togatwoam',exOne='$expones',exOneam='$exponeam',exTwo='$exptwos',exTwoam='$exptwoam',exThree='$exptree',exThreeam='$exptream',exFour='$expfors',exFouram='$expforam',exFive='$expfives',exFiveam='$expfiveam',exSix='$expsixs',exSixam='$expsixam',exSeven='$expsevs',exSevenam='$expsevam',exEight='$expeyts',exEightam='$expeytam',exNine='$expnines',exNineam='$expnineam',exTen='$exptens',exTenam='$exptenam',exElev='$expelevs',exElevam='$expelevam',totalMisc='$totalmiscexpenses',driverName='$drivername',driverSal='$driversal',helpName='$helpname',helpSal='$helpsal',totalExpense='$totalexpenses',income='$income',totalincome='$totalinc',date='$recdate',recdate= '$dt' WHERE id='$id'")or die('Failed');



if($queryupdate){ 

    echo "<script>alert('Record added.'); window.location='record_list.php'</script>";



            }
?>
```

Comment: Which textboxes are undefined?

Comment: Next time please take more care to format. When it is not a runnable snippet, just indent 4 spaces and post less code

Comment: Sorry sir its my first time to post.

Answer (score 0):

try to use $('#entryVal').serialize() like data: $('#entryVal').serialize()

Comment: $('#entryVal').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "updaterecord.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data:$('#entryVal').serialize()
     })
     .done(function(res){
         window.location('record_list.php');
    });
}); like this sir?

Comment: try removing the datatype prop

Answer (score 0):

to make this ajax script simple

```
$('#entryVal').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "updaterecord.php",
       data: $(this).serialize()
     })
     .done(function(res){
         window.location('record_list.php');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi sir Gian Tomakin, ive tried the code but it the data is not updating. also the value of textbox $totalmiscexpenses, $totalexpenses, $totalinc is not changing or updating. and it's not redirecting on the record_list.php

Comment: Sir Gian , should i remove the my variables on the jquery? such as var totalinc = $('#totalinc').val(); ? like that?

Comment: yep you can cause by using serialize you can already get all input value inside the form.

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you but when I click the update button nothings happend. can you help me please. and also i tried to echo the $id = $_GET['id']; from updaterecord.php but no output.

Comment: try echo $id = $_POST['ID'];

Comment: Hi sir gian, the code still didn't work. i don't know whats the problem why its not updating. when i pressed the update button, the browser is just refresh.